# Why i am getting empty array in response from AFN server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I call this method :

```
-(void)getdocschedule{

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *t = [prefs stringForKey:@"token"];
    NSString *seqid= [prefs stringForKey:@"seq_id"];
    NSLog(@"%@",t);
    NSLog(@"%@",seqid);

    AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/GetSchedule",del.Root_URL];


    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"id":seqid,

                             @"token":t

                             };

    //here we can see parameters which is sent to server

    NSLog(@"Sent parameter to image server  : %@",params);

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

    AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];

         [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

        // Here we can see response which is coming from server

        NSLog(@"Response from get schedule server:%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

I got response like :

```
Response from get schedule server:[]
```

But why am I getting response null? I didn't get that, where I am wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "AFN Server" ? you just got empty array as response from your server.

Comment: @Mahesh i'm using Afnetworking.... yes, i just got empty array from server.

Comment: did you tested your API with `Postman` ?

Comment: I'm not tested it on postman, but it works for my friend(android) with same url and same parameters... @Mahesh

Comment: i can't test it without API URL. come to chat for more discussion where i ping you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I think the problem is that you are using the Old Depreciated method of `AFHTTPSessionManager`. Change URL and params according to your requirement and then run.

P.S. Try to testing your API in POSTMAN and check it your API returns some data or not with your params.

```
-(void)getdocschedule{

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString *t = [prefs stringForKey:@"token"];
NSString *seqid= [prefs stringForKey:@"seq_id"];
NSLog(@"%@",t);
NSLog(@"%@",seqid);

NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",kAPIBaseURL,kLoginAPI];


NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"email":@"a@a.com",

                         @"password":@"Hello@1212"

                         };

//here we can see parameters which is sent to server

NSLog(@"Sent parameter to image server  : %@",params);

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];

AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

[policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

[policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];

manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];
[manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

}failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, NSError *error) {


      }];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your API's returns some data?

Comment: Then there is issue with your API. Your code is perfect.

Comment: but, for android, it works fine with same url and same parameters... Whats my problrm..?

Comment: Is your API uses GET method or POST?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131327/discussion-between-suraj-sukale-and-syed-e-hussaini).